# Minecraft mob effect that I added doesn't work properly [forge 1.19.2]

Tags: debugging, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I registered a new effect called "Hemorrhage" and made a file Hemorrhage.java which extends MobEffect where I override .applyEffectTick() and .isDurationEffectTick() to make my effect do stuff, but the effect doesn't work properly

Also the debugging with breakpoints works VERY weird in that file: if I use, for example, .hurt() inside .applyEffectTick() on the entity and put breakpoint on the line where the .hurt() method is used, debug works just fine, but if I don't use this method anywhere and put the breakpoint anywhere else in the .applyEffectTick(), the debug doesn't do anything, as if I just pressed [runClient]

What the "hemorrhage" is supposed to do: if the player stands still or moves while crouching, the effect deals 1 damage every 4 seconds; if the player moves while not crouching, the effect calculates player's horizontal movement speed and deals more damage based on that movements speed.

this is the haemorrhage.java file: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/c5cba090e503413daebb838779e44ed6

What actually happens is that the damage is ONLY dealt if the player is sprinting AND jumping

these are the lines where horizontal velocity is calculated:

> double dx = pLivingEntity.getDeltaMovement().x();
> double dz = pLivingEntity.getDeltaMovement().z();
> double velocity = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dz * dz);

Debugging shows me that velocity is calculated properly, but the program behaves as if velocity is ALWAYS 0, unless the player is sprinting AND jumping